# How create shared library in QT/QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I have 4 qml files and one main.cpp to load qml file.
Is it possible for me to create 1 dll file for those 4 qml file.
And use it in different application if so how to do that.

Comment: why would you want to do this? if its only qml files, just copy the qml files to the other application. Done.

Comment: @MrBlueSky In some cases, you wouldn't want raw QML (source code) exposed to the end-user.

Answer (score 6):

As already said, there is no need for embedding qml files only in a library. But of course you have the right to do all you want, even that. I know at least 2 ways to do that:

**1. Create binary resource file**
Prepare resource file containing qml files and then compile it:

```
rcc -binary plugin.qrc -o plugin.rcc
```

Now you can include this file into your application :

```
QResource::registerResource("plugin.rcc");
```

and use it as regular qrc file:

```
QResource::registerResource(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/plugin.rcc");
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/myfile.qml"));
```

Here `qml/` is prefix in resource file.

**2. Shared library**
Another way is to create a shared library containing the same resource file. For example your plugin's shared library implements following interface:

***interface.h***

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H
#define PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class PluginInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~PluginInterface() {}
    virtual QByteArray getQML(const QString &name) = 0;
};

#define PluginInterface_iid "org.qt-project.PluginInterface"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(PluginInterface, PluginInterface_iid)

#endif
```

and its implementation is:

```
QByteArray PluginImpl::getQML(const QString &name)
{
    QFile file(":/qml/" + name);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return QByteArray();
    return file.readAll();
}
```

Now, in your application you load your plugin and get its resource as a string:

```
QDir pluginsDir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath("plugin.dll"));
QObject *plugin = pluginLoader.instance();
if (plugin) {
    PluginInterface *pluginInstance = qobject_cast<PluginInterface *>(plugin);
    if (pluginInstance) {
        QByteArray content = pluginInstance->getQML("file1.qml");
        QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
        QQmlComponent component(view->engine());
        component.setData(content, QUrl());
        QQuickItem *childItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.create());
        childItem->setParentItem(view->contentItem());

        QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
        container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);
    }
}
```

*But pay attention, when you deploy your application you anyway have to copy all qml system files, like #QTPATH/qml/QtQml, #QTPATH/qml/QtQuick.2, #QTPATH/qml/QtQuick.2 etc.*

Links:

- [Resource compiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/rcc.html)
- [Same theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040838/large-qt-external-binary-resource-file)
- [Plugin example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-echoplugin-example.html)

Comment: When deploying the deploy tool correctly recognised dependencies both on Win and MacOS, granted the ` qmldir` parameter is used. If I were you I world have added that. Btw nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the documentation for [QML Modules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-topic.html)

There are options for QML-only modules, C++ only and mixed mode.