# Can you import a QML file from a different project?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to build a library of some of the common classes/functions and (hopefully) QML components that I've made between projects.

I created a Shared Library and have the classes/functions loading properly, but when I try to  include a QML file it says "qrc:/main.qml:4:1: "../SharedLib/QMLFiles": no such directory" (but it does exist).

Do I have to do something else to use a Shared Libraries QML files in another project, or is this just not possible right now?

This is the QML file for my project (not the shared library).

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

import "../SharedLib/QMLFiles"

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SharedComponent {

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Qt5. In Qt6, they heavily push the use of modules which is *supposed* to make this type of thing easier. Modules are still a thing in Qt5, but you have to do more things manually. Are your qml files in a resource file?

Comment: @JarMan I am using Qt5. In the SharedLibrary they are in a filter titled QML (it auto added it there when I added a new QML file to the project). I'm not sure if I can add a resource file to the SharedLibrary can I? And if I can would that make the file importable from an external project?

Comment: You can create a resource file for a shared library. Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968813/how-create-shared-library-in-qt-qml)?

Comment: The way we organize a large application with reusable libraries if through the use of `git submodules`. This allows you to pick the version of the library you want to use, not necessarily the latest. As a submodule, it will appear as a pseudo subdirectory to your project, but, be managed in a different git repo with its own issue management and tracking. Because it appears as a submodule, you refer to it in your qrc as if it was part of your project. After you worked with this for a bit, you'll realize this process works really well with Qt/QML.

Comment: As an example of this, check out https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo